# GCD without using recursion

Tags: python-3.x

The code given below is only working correctly for some of the inputs such as gcdIter(2, 12) which gives me correct output i.e 2 but if I give input as gcdIter(220,120) it gives me 110 instead of 20. I need some help with the logic.

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    '''
    a, b: positive integers

    returns: a positive integer, the greatest common divisor of a & b.
    '''
    if a<b:
        while a>0:
            if b%a==0:
                print('the gcd is : '+''+str(a))
                break
            else:
                a -= 1
    else:
         while b>0:
            if a%b==0:
                print('the gcd is :'+''+str(b))
                break
            else:
                b -= 1
```

Comment: Sorry, but your code make no sense to me. What's the point of `a -= 1`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: i am just decrementing the value of a and checking it again for getting the correct answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> it's simple like that.No need to check `a<b` or `a>b`

```
def gcdIter(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a%b
    print('the gcd is :'+str(a))
```

Comment: sorry!! but i didn't got this part "a, b = b, a%b"

Comment: a,b = b, a%b is just short form of a=b & b = a%b :)